# Must declare the scalar variable @colname

Tags: sql, exception, parameters, dataadapter

I have a dataadapter, which I've created through the IDE.  I've given it a query, similar to the following (I've simplified it by removing extra criteria and columns):

```
SELECT     *
FROM         MyView
WHERE    (Colname like '%' + @colname + '%')
```

The code generated looks like the following:

```
Public Overloads Overridable Function FillBySearchCriteria(ByVal dataTable As MaqisDataSet.VFleetDataTable, ByVal __colname As String) As Integer
            Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(1)
            If (__rego Is Nothing) Then
                Throw New Global.System.ArgumentNullException("__colname")
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = CType(__colname, String)
            End If
            If (Me.ClearBeforeFill = true) Then
                dataTable.Clear
            End If
            Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
            Return returnValue
       End Function
```

When I execute this (whether I pass a value in through __colname, or leave it as empty, either way) I hit this exception:

> OleDbException (0x80040e14): Must declare the scalar variable "@colname".

I don't know what is causing this, I've added some debugging, and there seems to be a valid parameter, with the name "@colname" in the SelectCommand.Parameters collection.

This is the trace:

```
[OleDbException (0x80040e14): Must declare the scalar variable "@colname".]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1003520
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +255
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +188
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +161
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +116
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +4
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +130
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +162
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +115
```

Any help in finding the cause would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think for defining a parameter outside of a stored procedure you'd just define the query 'where' as `WHERE (Colname like '%' + ? + '%')`.

Comment: You need to add the parameter @colname to your command.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `declare @colname colnametype` to your query?

Comment: @bendataclear: I'm not sure how I then assign more than one variable.  This method has definately worked with named variables in the past.  And since I need to eventually have more than one criteria, I'm not sure how your approach works.

Comment: @Fortunato: If I add declare statements, they then override what I pass through using the parameters in the parameters collection (described by Allan).  Are you suggesting I then dynamically add a series of 'set' statements in code?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thanks, the parameter was added during configuration, I forgot to mention that in the question. But it was all configured using the wizard.  I added some checking in to see that it is appearing in the command parameters collection, and it is appearing as normal, with name and value assigned correctly... the error still seems to appear

Comment: It's the the line: Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = (where .Parameters(0).ParameterName = "@colname") <- I've verified this